# Issue with Pine Script stdev() function

Tags: .net, pine-script, stdev

I am a little bit confused on how stdev() function in TradingView's script language works.

I am trying to write a C# code that converts the following code block but I am getting different results:

```
typical=hlc3
f = log( typical ) - log( typical[1] )
g = stdev(f, 30 )
```

Basically, what I am doing in C# is to create a list of decimal values and then i do a Stdev on the list but I am unable to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I believe pine `stdev()` calcuates population stdev. If you're C# code is calculating sample stdev that might account for the difference (`N` instead of `N - 1`)